# Practical Relevance of Signals in C

Tags: c

What is a practical relevance of signals in C programs ?
Where do we need signals. I am getting confused and feeling traped in this topic, Who generates signals ?

Comment: `kill -9 yourapp`. boom. one signal that kills your app.

Comment: C has no intrinsic support for signals.

Comment: @MartinJames: No? `<signal.h>` is part of the standard-library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signals are in C because signals were how you communicated with a process in the original version of UNIX.

They are a fairly simple way of allowing your process to respond to external requests such as "re-read my config file", for example.

The K&R chapter is a good intro, but read the C standard to see the minimum for what is defined. In particular, the only portable thing you can do in a signal handler is either abort the process, or set an atomic flag which your main thread of execution will check in due course.   In practice, people do more complicated things in signal handlers such as making system calls.

Answer (score 1):

Signals are a lightweight way for processes to communicate with each other asynchronously; as such, it shouldn't be a surprise that processes generate signals.

Comment: So who generates signal ? User or System ?

Comment: Either can; or, more formally, either can *request* a signal.

Comment: How could this be done to request a signal ? is this request from some other process or system ?

Answer (score 0):

Signals provide a way of supporting asynchronous interrupts in a C program.  That said, the C spec is almost completely void of specified behavior for signals, leaving them essentially entirely up to the implementation, so writing portable code that uses signals is almost impossible.  You need to carefully read the documentation for your implementation to see what exactly signals can do.